# I can't call pymongo in the python shell

Tags: python, macos, mongodb, shell, installation

I'm trying to use pymongo in the IDLE shell on MAC OS X 10.9, but I can only do it in terminal.

when I call `import pymongo` in IDLE I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pymongo
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

but I use python in terminal I get this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2013, 21:33:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>>
```

I can then use it with MongoDB.

Have I made some sort of install error? I'm doing this to learn mongoDB so I'm relatively new to this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the Python version information exactly the same in the IDLE shell?  Chances are that the IDLE you are using is from a different version of Python installed on your machine.

Comment: The python version in Terminal is 2.7.5, where as the IDLE version is 3.3.4, also I just edited the question as it should be mac OS X 10.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the information you supplied in the comments, it appears you have installed a version of Python 3.3.4 on your system but you have installed the PyMongo distribution to an instance of Python 2.7, probably the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7 shipped with OS X 10.9.  When you install a third-party package (or "distribution"), it is normally associated only with the Python instance that you used to install it.  There are several common ways to install such packages.  One way is to use the `easy_install` command, as is suggested on the PyMongo page.  However, the `easy_install` command is also associated with  a particular Python instance.  On recent OS X releases, Apple supplies `easy_install` commands that are associated with and install into the system Pythons.  So it's a common pitfall on OS X to install a newer version of Python alongside the system Python but then use the default `easy_install` command with the result that the package you want ends up installed in the wrong Python version.  One solution is to install a separate version of `easy_install` for each Python version you install.  The `easy_install` command is provided by the [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) package.  However, these days the recommended installer tool for Python is [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) which provides more features than `easy_install`, including the ability to uninstall packages, and is actively supported in the community.

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
python3.3 get-pip.py
python3.3 -m pip install pymongo
python3.3 -c "import pymongo; print(pymongo.version)"
-> 2.6.3
```

You also need to install a version of `pip` for each Python instance that you use.  There are other ways to invoke `pip` but, by using the way shown above, you know which version of Python you are using and you are less likely to end up with the situation you have now.   There are other tools you can use in addition, like [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), but, particularly on OS X, `pip` should be sufficient to handle most beginning use cases.